# Getting RuntimeException: Binary XML file line: You must supply a layout_width attribute . Where is the attribute missing?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Im getting the following runtime error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #15: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

I've checked my code multiple times but I can't find any place where I've missed a layout_width attribute. Where is the problem?

**item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:id="@+id/myDate"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/myDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myTime"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:context="com.example.nirvan.recyclerview.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.recyclerview.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android:android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    layout_height="match_parent"
    layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<android:android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    layout_height="match_parent"
    layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"/>
```

should be

```
<android:android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"/>
```

Comment: They are both the same? How is this the answer ?

Comment: @Mysterious_android try it [here](https://www.diffchecker.com)